# Is it possible to launch a script using node while the files are hosted on a server?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if this exact question has come up before because no matter what I can't find the correct wording for my situation.

I have a folder on my desktop called "Script". Inside this folder I have a bunch of different files and folders.

I also have a .bat file that says:

```
cd "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Script/"
node file.js
```

inside of it. All this does is execute the file using node.

Now here's my problem, I want other people to be able to launch this script as well without giving them all the files. I can't have them see the source code for the script.

So I was wondering if I uploaded the entire folder to my web host, is there a possible way for a command like

```
cd "websitehostname.com/files/"
node file.js
```

and then the script would execute on their computer just as it was on mine? Or is this not possible.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Whats wrong with zipping the files and distributing them that way?

Comment: @Deadron I'm trying to host a botting client for people to use. Once they run the script, it controls the users mouse movement according to the script. If I zip the files and distribute it, they will unzip and see the code. The code should always been hidden.

Comment: `can't have them see the source code for the script.` what do you try to hide? Or why is it important that they should not see the soruce code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem.

If not letting people see the source code is the necessity. I would rather suggest you compile an uglified/obfuscated version of the source code and then send it across to people.

You could understand more about code obfuscation [here](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator)

Most of the websites do the same.

You could even compile your source code into native code using [Enclose JS](http://enclosejs.com/) library

Comment: Sorry for the late response but if I send a uglified version, will they be able to decompile it or something?

Comment: No. I believe once you send an obfuscated version of your code, it's nearly impossible for someone to read through the code.

You could also use a module like Enclose JS to compile your code to native code.

Comment: The obfuscated code is still JavaScript, and names (except of some functions and variables) still exists. So reading obfuscated code after you run a prettifier over it is not that hard. @JordanBrown

Comment: I decided to run pkg to compile my code as an .exe along with a more obfuscated code base. Hopefully they can't decompile the .exe. I couldn't figure out a way how to decompile it which it technically good. @t.niese